# Dropping the same column name from mutiple tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to delete a same column present in many tables. for e.g. column with name say 'c' is present in many tables..t1,t2,t3...

One solution is to write as many `ALTER` statements to drop a column as the number of tables having that column.

is there any way where I can do the same thing using single `ALTER` table statement.

Comment: You can use [`all_tables`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm) and [`all_tab_columns`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm) to generate your statements using PL-SQL. See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927012/dropping-multiple-columns-plsql-and-user-tab-cols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  An `ALTER TABLE` statement can not alter more than one table at a time.  You could write some dynamic SQL based on `ALL_TAB_COLS` e.g.

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ' DROP COLUMN '|| column_name || ';'
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE column_name = 'MY_UNWANTED_COLUMN'
AND owner = 'MY_OWNER'
/
```

then run that script.  You might want to add

```
AND table_name IN ('MY_TAB1','MY_TAB2')
```

to specify an exact list of tables for extra piece of mind.